# Не выполняется sql запрос в php, как исправить ошибку?

Tags: php, sql

Есть sql запрос в php:

```
$sql 'UPDATE `_spi`
SET `w_st`=`w_t`+`w_s`+`w_z`+`w_p`
CASE WHEN `p_m` =  'IV'
THEN `w_t`+`w_s`
ELSE 0
END';
```

Но при выполнение получаю ошибку:

```
PHP Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'IV' (T_STRING)
```

В чем ошибка? Подскажите пожалуйста.

дополняю, экранировал строку

```
$sql 'UPDATE `_spi`
SET `w_st`=`w_t`+`w_s`+`w_z`+`w_p`
CASE WHEN `p_m` =  \'IV\'
THEN `w_t`+`w_s`
ELSE 0
END';
```

Ошибки больше нет, вроде как запрос проходит, но теперь не считает.
Если поле p_m равно IV, то всё равно считается не как в

> THEN `w_t`+`w_s`

, а как в

> SET `w_st`=`w_t`+`w_s`+`w_z`+`w_p`

Comment: У вас одинарные кавычки в середине строки, которая сама в одинарных кавычках. Экранируйте или кавычки меняйте. А вообще почитайте как строки в php пишутся https://www.php.net/manual/ru/language.types.string.php

Comment: Менял на двойные " ошибка оставалась.

Comment: Нужно экранировать строки

Comment: Вот прямо такая же ошибка оставалась ? А то у вас еще знака равенства нет ...

Comment: Ну вообще у вас сейчас в запросе написано что если IV то считать как 2w_t+2w_s+w_z+w_p

Comment: Стоп, оно у вас вообще посчитаться ни как не может. у вас синтаксическая ошибка в sql запросе, у вас case вообще в воздухе висит. Вам когда в предыдущем вопросе ответ предлагали, то там совершенно по другому было, там значение case прибавлялось к остальной формуле (без пары полей в основной формуле). Т.е. там был оператор сложения, а у вас его нет. Вы хоть после попытки выполнить запрос на ошибки проверяете, ошибки печатаете ? А то ведь вслупую никогда не разберетесь где какие ошибки остались. Да и запрос надо выполнять не из php для начала, а из какой нибудь программы для прямой работы с БД